# R: Permuted-Block Randomization with Varying Block Sizes

Tags: r, random, experimental-design

Here is a provisional solution to the question I posed earlier. It seems to work, but when I look at the shuffling that `ddply` does I wonder if it is, in fact, random. Some of the splits seem unfortunate, like `BAAAAB` in block 4. I had thought about repeatedly shuffling using `ddply` but am interested in seeing other potential solutions.

```
#### Load packages ####

require(plyr)

#### Create randomization ####

set.seed(1984)
nBlocks <- 1:9
sBlocks <- c( sample( c(rep(3,4), rep(6,3)) ), sample( c(3,6) ) )
trtGroup <- c("A","B")
trtRatio <- 2:1
rand <- data.frame( block=rep(nBlocks, sBlocks), treatment=rep(trtGroup, trtRatio) )
rand <- ddply(rand[sample(row.names(rand)), ], .(block))
rand
```

Question:

I recently learned how to perform permuted-block randomization with varying block sizes using the SAS Plan Procedure. I have been trying to figure out how to do the same thing using R. The `blockrand` and the `experiment` packages do not allow for unequal numbers of patients across treatment groups.

Suppose I want to randomly assign 30 patients to a experimental group and a control group at a  2:1 ratio (i.e., N=20 in the experimental group and N=10 in the control group). Further suppose that I want 3 blocks of 6 patients and 4 blocks of 3 patients and that I want to randomly vary the block sizes. How do I do that using R?

Comment: Do you always want 2 different block sizes, are blocks allowed to include one subject only?

Comment: For this example, I need 3 blocks of 6 patients and 4 blocks of 3 patients. That gives a total of 30 patients. In each block of 6, I need 4 patients to be randomly assigned to the experimental group and 2 patients to the control group. In each block of 3, I need 2 patients to be randomly assigned to the experimental group and 1 patient to be randomly assigned to the control group. The length of the blocks also needs to vary randomly. So, for example, by chance, it might start out with a block of 6 followed by 2 blocks of 3, etc.. Blocks of 1 probably shouldn't occur with this sort of design.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
set.seed(12345)
allocation <- NULL  
block <- sample(c(rep(1,4),rep(2,3)),7)
for(i in 1:7){ 
  tallocation <- sample(c(rep(0,block[i]),rep(1,block[i]*2)), 3*block[i]) 
  allocation <- c(allocation, tallocation)
}
```

Comment: Hi Jan, Thanks for your response. Might be the start of a good solution but am not sure. Can you take a look at the provisional solution I posted in updating my question? I'd be interested in getting your feedback on what I've done there.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy in `randomizr`:

```
install.packages("randomizr")
library(randomizr)
block <- c(rep(1:3, each = 6), rep(4:7, each = 3))
Z <- block_ra(block, prob = 2/3)
table(block, Z)
```

`Z` is a vector of length 30.  You can see the distribution of treatments:

```
> table(block, Z)
     Z
block 0 1
    1 2 4
    2 2 4
    3 2 4
    4 1 2
    5 1 2
    6 1 2
    7 1 2
```